# App Action Test Tool plugging error on android studio

Tags: android, google-assistant

Hi I'm getting this Error on Google Assistant plugging on Android studio when try to run

*Google Assistant plugin v5.0.0
Preview Creation Error Status Code: 400 Message: Precondition check failed. - The actions.xml contained a resource that failed to parse, A '' element must be enclosed in a '' element.*

I'm doing the implementation of Google Actions for mobile and tv app. For mobile it's just working perfect, but with the same shortcuts and config on TV ( with leanback ), when I try to launch the "Create preview", it's showing this popup:

[Popup of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E57H4.png)

and a link to shortcuts.xml documentation.

We don't have nothing about the old features of actions.xml, so we don't understand why the plugin is trying to check a file that don't even be there. Can this be a bug from the plugging? we are stuck to release the features for the TV app version.

Thanks.